# successive relative positioning tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I wanted to get a triangle by positioning nodes in relative to each other. Here is what I did

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4em]

% Gridline
\draw [step=0.5cm,draw=gray] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);

\coordinate (A) at (-4,+4);

\draw [blue] (A) -- +(1,0) -- +(0,-1) -- (A) %line1
\draw [green] (A) -- +(1,0) -- ($ (A) + (1,0) $)+(0,-1) -- (A);  %line2

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Problem:
**LINE-1:** All points are positioned relative to A. I thought that "+(1,0) -- +(0,-1)" will place (0,-1) relative to A+(1,0) but that didnt happen.

**LINE-2:** For this line points are at right position but leg is missing at "+(1,0) -- ($ (A) + (1,0) $)+(0,-1)"

how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look in `pgfmanual`? This is a fragment from page 140 explaining that your problem comes because you wanted to use `--++` but used `--+`.

[image]